# Do I use has been or have been?

Tags: grammar, tenses

When writing this sentence "Mrs. Jones, and many other teachers, _____ been grading papers." Do I use have or had, and why?

Comment: The title is asking about *has* vs *have*, while the body is asking about *have* vs *had*. Please clarify.

Comment: Are they still grading the papers?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with user 772922, but here is a fuller explanation of the grammar rules.

"Have" and "has" are conjugations of the auxiliary verb used in the present perfect tense. The choice of which one to use has nothing to do with the tense. It is simply dictated by the subject of the verb -- in other words, "who" has or have or had been.

The present perfect tense is used to convey an action that began in the past and continues in the present.

Here is the conjugation of the verb "to be" in the present perfect tense:
I have been
We have been
You have been
He/She/It has been
They have been

The past perfect tense is used to convey something that happened in the past, a past that occurred before another, later action in the past that you happen to be discussing, as in, "I had made the cookies before we ate."

Here is the conjugation of the verb "to be" in the past perfect tense:
I had been
We had been
You had been
He/She/It had been
They had been

And that's the rule!

Regarding the original question, it does seem that the subject is not the singular Mrs. Jones, but a plural "they" that includes both Mrs. Jones and a lot of other teachers. So you would use either "have been" or "had been" (but not "has been"). The choice is up to the author, depending on which tense is to be conveyed.

I hope that's helpful.

The site's rules ask for sources. Lots of sources, including the Chicago Manual of Style and a ream of English grammar textbooks I was given throughout my K-12 education, including the once ubiquitous Heath Handbook of English.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use *have been* instead of *has been* if it is talking about present and *had been* if it is talking about past, because here we are talking about many others teachers with Mrs. Jones, and whenever we talk about more people we use *have* instead of *has*.

Comment: What if this is a chronology, and the teachers had been grading papers but then were called to a meeting?